# sql decode with assumed null value - unexpected result

Tags: sql, oracle

I cannot understand the result from the following query:

```
select 
  trim(custodian) CUST, 
  length(trim(custodian)) LNGTH, 
  ascii(trim(custodian)) ASCII, 
  decode(trim(custodian), null, 'EMPTY', 'NOT EMPTY') DECOD
from collateral_detail 
where booking_id = '36795';
```

Output:

```
CUST     LNGTH     ASCII     DECOD     
-------- --------- --------- ----------- 
         1         0         NOT EMPTY
```

Data is loaded using SQL Loader, Oracle 9i database.

When I manually set custodian value to null or '', decode returns 'EMPTY' as expected.

Comment: `custodian` has one non-space character and that has an ASCII value of `\000`.  `trim()` doesn't remove this character.

Comment: There might be a carriage return inside that field or a line feed character.